Do higher lottery jackpots cause gambling disorders?
Is there any evidence for the mainstream view below, that loftier lottery jackpots cause gambling disorders?

The biggest jackpot in the history of the game fell in 2003. After a couple of rollovers, the sum had reached approximately 70 million US dollars. The lucky drawing produced 13 top-prize winners. Each one of them went home 5.4 million dollars richer.
When this massive jackpot came into existence, Lotto 6/45 was subjected to massive criticism. According to opponents, such serious sums were to lead to lotto fever, making many people spend excessive sums of money on the acquisition of tickets.
At the time, the price of the ticket was approximately 2 dollars. Due to the serious social pressure, the ticket price was reduced. This is how the prize pool decreased, as well, preventing the game from producing such massive jackpots again.

Gambling disorders are defined on p. 6, in the Centre for Addiction and Mental Health's Gambling Policy Framework dated March 27 2024.

However, the more a person gambles, the more
likely they are to experience harm.17


Gambling problems can be viewed as a spectrum. The
Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-
5)—the authority for psychiatric diagnoses in North
America—recognizes problem gambling as an addictive
disorder akin to those associated with substances like alcohol or opioids.18 Formally referred to as gambling
disorder (or prior to 2013, pathological gambling), it is
described as “persistent and recurrent maladaptive
gambling behavior that disrupts personal, family, and/or
vocational pursuits.”18  (See Appendix for diagnostic criteria.)


Welcome user. You've asked a question about a complex subject where causation may not apply. Would you be able to show us your current level of understanding of the role of causation in this and the factors involved. Please [edit] to add that.

It doesn't look to me as though the claim in the text is: "Higher jackpots cause more gambling disorders." Rather, the claim seems to be: "Higher jackpots are more popular." I do understand that slot machines and lotteries have both generally increased jackpots to increase revenues. I'm not sure that this translates to more gambling disorders, any more than sales events increase shopping addiction.

@ArnonWeinberg The text doesn't outright moot "gambling disorders". But "lotto fever" and "excessive" suggest gambling disorders.
